# Next Iteration need to be start, if the current iteration is completed in the FOR or WHILE loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Currently i am developing script in python using scrapy and seleniumm. Bascially a spider to scrape a website. I experienced the site is very slow while paginating. Below i have attached the image of the pagination

[Website Pagination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00v34.png)

When i click the pagination numbers, it consumes more time and loading screen is coming when click the number of pagination to paginate (below is the loading screen, it loads above the current record table). This pagination is based on Ajax (if im not wrong, because its seems not page refreshing).

[Pagination Loading Screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Prw0.png)

The Code i have developed is, clicking pagination is based on `while` loop, its just iterating, even the next set of data loaded or not loaded. `while` is just looping by not checking the records being loaded. I even have set `time.sleep(5)`. Unfortunately the loop is just iterating. The pagination is very slow. It needs more time to load but we can't say how much time it needs to load. Depends on the traffic and bandwidth of the internet and the website traffic.

The sample code which i have developed

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5, poll_frequency=1)

while True:

#data saving process works here

try:
    #Pagination xpath
    next_page = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="dxpCtrl"]//td[@class="dxpPageNumber dxpCurrentPageNumber"]/following-sibling::td[@class="dxpPageNumber"]')))
    
    if 'aspxGVPagerOnClick' in next_page.get_attribute('onclick'):
        #Click pagination 1, 2, 3, 4,  ....
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        break
except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I need while loop should be iterate, until the next records set has been loaded in the site when clicking next pagination number. Until that iteration should be paused. Help me to solve this thread. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried changing the ```time.sleep()``` parameter to something like 10 or 15? To see if that works better?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur this site always has a slowness, it might take minutes to load even. Unfortunately. I wish have any deadlocks to solve the problem. I am new to python as well

Comment: Only changing the page, does a part of it refresh, or the entire page reloads?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur it does refresh any page, basically retrieve data from Ajax (jquery) calls

Comment: ```next_page = wait.until``` why isn't this working then?